# What do these brackets in viewport overlay text mean?

Tags: interface

I'm still pretty new to Blender 2.8, and all of the sudden these symbols (<>) started showing up next to the name of every object. What do they mean?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

According to the manual, as stated in [*3D View* documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/startup_scene.html#text-info), it is the name of the current marker.

[image]

The fact that there are only brackets with nothing between them probably means it has been renamed into a blank name.